# Storing multiple values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I store more than one value returned from query in mysql? My requirement is I want to perform while loop based on that value. Searched all document but could not find it.

I tried this

```
    SET @last = (SELECT ei.last_date  FROM emp_details emp
                INNER JOIN emp_inactive ei  ON emp.id = ei.emp_id);
    SELECT @last;
```

But got an error Subquery returns more than 1 row.how can I do this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi juergen, I am new to this can you please provide me any links

Comment: A loop in SQL or PHP? If the former its often possible to use set based operations ...

Comment: hi Alex,a loop in SQL .

Comment: Google *mysql temp table*

Comment: If you want to process each `last_date` individually you would use a `CURSOR` http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/ but if you describe what you want to do with each value someone may suggest a better (i.e. non loop) approach.

Comment: My problem is I want to update one flag if that last date = current date. I thought of using this way select all last dates and check last  date=current date and perform update. But I got solution just an update query is enough to deal with this.   Thanks for helping me